# How to reveal the surrogate pairs in String in perl

Tags: perl, unicode, surrogate-pairs

I am working a perl code base to validate customer input, my goal is to block surrogate characters.

My thought is first encoding the customer input as UTF-16 and

```
 foreach my $messageChar (@MessageChars) {
   my $messageCharUTF16 = Encode::encode("UTF-16", $messageChar);
   if (($messageCharUTF16 >= 0xD800 && $messageCharUTF16 <= 0xDBFF)|( $messageCharUTF16 >= 0xDC00 && $messageCharUTF16 <= 0xDFFF)) {
      // Then we have surrogate pairs       
   }   
 }
```

However, I am not getting the correct UTF-16 values from Encode::encode.

How can I reveal the surrogate pairs? Is there any straight-forward way to verify if a string contains surrogate characters in Perl?

Answer (score 4):

It's not clear to me what you want to check, so I shall cover both possibilities.

---

**To check if a decoded string contains any of U+D800..U+DFFF**

The official Unicode standard says that no UTF forms, including UTF-16, can encode these code points, and Perl obliges.

```
$ perl -e'use open ":std", ":encoding(UTF-8)"; print "ABC\N{U+D800}DEF\n";'
Unicode surrogate U+D800 is illegal in UTF-8 at -e line 1.
"\x{d800}" does not map to utf8 at -e line 1.
ABC\x{D800}DEF
```

To check for those characters, you can use

```
$str =~ /[\x{D800}-\x{DFFF}]/
```

To check for any encoding error, you can use

```
eval { encode("UTF-8", $str, Encode::FB_CROAK | Encode::LEAVE_SRC); 1 }
```

---

**To check if a decoded string contains a character above U+FFFF**

Characters above U+FFFF can't be encoded using UCS-2, and require a surrogates to encode using UTF-16.

```
$ perl -e'use open ":std", ":encoding(UTF-16le)"; print "\N{U+10000}";' | od -t x2
0000000 d800 dc00
0000004
```

To check for those characters, you can use

```
$str =~ /[^\0-\x{FFFF}]/
```